# Can I get the "Diamonds to you!" achievement in singleplayer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements

How can one get the "Diamonds to you!" achievement in singleplayer? The achievement list cannot be completed without it. Perhaps it can be possible by passing a diamond to a zombie?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Yes**, you can get the "Diamonds to you!" achievement in singleplayer. There are 2 ways to get it. The first is precisely what you describe; you can throw a diamond at a zombie, and if they pick it up, it counts for the achievement. Not all zombies will pick things up though, so you may need to try a couple zombies.

The other way you can earn this achievement for a singleplayer world is to open the world to LAN. This may not be possible if you don't have another player, but it is an alternative method if you do have someone else that can connect to your world over LAN.

Comment: Thanks for confirming by thought. But I must inform you that starting a LAN world is some kind of multiplayer.Anyway,the LAN option is a variant,as I can get on the other computer,bring that player to the other,then I can throw to the other player.

Comment: @John I am well aware, however, it doesn't require you to set up a server or anything like that. You just have to have another person and press a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can summon a zombie that picks up items! Command: /summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {CanPickUpLoot:true} You need to have cheats and hard difficulty on!

Answer (score -2):

I know this post is old, but if any players who are new may find this useful.

If you have a crazy world find a plain or savannah or any biome but make sure its large, give diamonds to a zombie if it doesnt take kill it and keep doing it.

Comment: You could find a Zombie Dungeon as well...

Comment: yes i found couples btw In easy mode no zombies will pick up items